# How to edit an existing controller in Ckan through a plugin?

Tags: plugins, controller, ckan

1 of the adjustments I want to make is to edit the admin.py file in the controllers list. For example, the function def _get_config_form_items(self):
I want to remove some of the default items, but i don't know how to edit the file without changing it in the core.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove some items from the config, I don't recommend you to overwrite that part of the code. First, go through [the tutorial](http://docs.ckan.org/en/latest/extensions/tutorial.html) for writing an extension. Add to your plugin the [iConfigurer](http://docs.ckan.org/en/latest/extensions/plugin-interfaces.html?highlight=iconfigurer#ckan.plugins.interfaces.IConfigurer) interface and now you can remove or update config items.